# Azure Dev/Test Lab Tasks

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Being interested in the Azure DevTest Lab I watched the video [Introducing Azure DevTest Lab](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Microsoft-Azure/AzureCon-2015/ACON219) and at minute 15:21 there is a rare screenshot that shows some release tasks that look very interesting:

[image]

Especially **Azure Dev/Test Lab Provisioning** and **Azure Dev/Test Lab Remove Environment**.

I searched and searched but cannot find a way to get to these tasks? Does anyone know where to find these? Are these tasks available on-premises (TFS 2015)?

Any information is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are likely currently in development and not publicly released yet.  In many cases the VSTS team can enable tasks for you in private preview mode so you can try them early.  Use the VSTS contact page to request early access -

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/cloud-services-assisted-support-vs

Comment: Mmh, ok. That would also explain the search box and some other new things in this dialog... Thanks.

Comment: You can also just use  PowerShell ☺

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the devtestlabs tasks for VSTS are not standard, but they can be found in the market place if you ever need them. See below
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuredevtestlabs.tasks